# My flutter app login screen is working on android 8 version and up but not less than 8

Tags: android, flutter, api, authentication

I have a delivery app and this app is working fine with android version 8 and up but in less than 8 the first screen is login and when I pressed on login button it did not do anything and there is nothing that appears on the android studio IDE run part. I am using API to login.

Comment: What's the `minSdkVersion` defined in `android/app/build.gradle` for your app?

Comment: minSdkVersion 20, because I am using google_maps. the application is installed fine on devices less than the android 8 version.

Comment: It's hard to guess what could go wrong, you should provide more info. Please, read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, you can tell me what kind of info do you want to be provided?

Comment: The error you are getting, Android configuration files (e.g. build.gradle), `flutter doctor` results, etc. - whatever could help to reproduce the issue and get enough context.

Comment: Please add more logs from logcat and device info and app/build.gradle file as well